# No keyboard/mouse after waking from hibernate Macbook Pro Early 2011

Tags: macbook-pro

Having a problem since I installed either 10.8.1 or 10.8.2 (can't be sure which one -- I don't often let it get into hibernate).

Problem is that when the battery runs out and it hibernates to save the state of RAM, when it wakes up there is no mouse or keyboard.

The screen is responsive and stuff is happening (like reconnecting to WiFi).

Any ideas?